# Struggling to install pygtk with pip

Tags: python, pip, pygtk

I am trying to install pygtk using pip on Windows. Initially i get an error saying 
"ERROR: Could not import dsextras module: Make sure you have installed pygobject."

So when I try installing pygobject I get an error saying
"ERROR: Could not find pkg-config: please check your PATH environment variable"

Pretty new to Python so could be making a stupid mistake but does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on my Window 7 machine, and solved it by installing the prebuilt PyGTK executables, which I found here: http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pygtk/2.22/.

I installed the "pygtk-all-in-one-...." for my version of Python (2.7).