# Installing Python GTK

Tags: python, windows, path, gtk, environment-variables

I have recently stated a arduino project for my engineering class. I mange to get python to talk to arduino via serial communication. Now I can send data to the board, I want to be able to set up a graphical user interface GUI with GTK, so that the user and push a button in the GUI and a LED turns on. However, I am trying to install the GTK liberty and I am running into a  lot of problems.

**Problem:** 
 I download GTK via pyip, when I run the set up file in the command line it says 
you have to install pyobject. So i went back to pyip and download the pyobject module and run the set up file. When I run the set up file I get this error message ***"ERROR: Could not find pkg-config: Please check your PATH environment variable."*** I downloaded the pyconfig  from pyip ran it and the set up ran fine. But when i went to install pyobject I keep getting this error. Can someone direct tell me how to install GTK properly or how to fix my problem. 
PS I try setting my windows environment to the location of my pkg-config file.

Error from Installer

[image: this is what i get when i start the exe]

CMD error :[image: Error from cmd]

Help would be deeply appreciated

Thanks

Sean From Boxing Studio Games

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26323732/struggling-to-install-pygtk-with-pip) I think.

Comment: @IronManMark20: I'm not sure if it's a dup… but it's at least worth trying the explicit `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` mentioned in one of the answers there (which wasn't appropriate to that question, but might be to this one).

Comment: Except that answer is completely wrong, so… never mind.

Comment: First, `pyconfig` and `pkg-config` are not the same thing. You still need to install `pkg-config`.

Comment: Hmm... your right, but the answer might be there...

Comment: Do you know a fast and easier way to install the library ? I tried the installers and it say it cannot find my python 2.7, but I have python 2.7 compiling on my machine fine.

Comment: Do you actually want Gtk+2 rather than Gtk+3?

Comment: Also, make sure your Python, Gtk+, and PyGtk+ or Py-GObject are all for the same bitness; you can't use a 32-bit Python with a 64-bit Gtk+ or vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use the latest all-in-one installer for pyGTK. You can find it [here](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pygtk/2.24/).

It should automagically install all of the dependencies for pyGTK.

Comment: When I try to install I get a message saying that "Python version 2.7 required, which was not found in the registry" I upload the error message

Comment: Is python in the system PATH variable?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is that you're trying to find non-Python prerequisites via `pip`.

You say "I download GTK via pyip", I don't know any package manager named `pyip`. If you mean `pip`, that only installs Python packages; it doesn't help get the DLLs and other files that are needed to build those Python packages. In particular, to install the Python bindings for Gtk+ and do anything useful with them, you have to have Gtk+ itself. You can get a nice installer package from [the Gtk website](http://www.gtk.org/download/index.php).

Also, you have to be precise with names. If you're missing `pkg-config`, installing something called `pyconfig` isn't going to help; they have nothing to do with each other. Similarly, `pip` is the Python package installer; `pyip` is a library for dealing with raw IP packets; they have nothing to do with each other.

At any rate, the Gtk+ binaries should have all the prerequisites you need. Then `pip` should be able to install the Python bindings… assuming you have a compiler set up properly. But somehow, I have a feeling that you don't have one set up, and don't know how.

Fortunately, [Christoph Gohlke's repo](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) has prebuilt binary wheels for almost anything you could want in Python that's hard to build for Windows. Just download the `.whl` files you need from that package, and follow the instructions on the page to install them with `pip`.

Comment: Sorry about that I was wrong I meant to say pip not pyip

Comment: @user2566626: I can guess what you mean, but Windows and Python can't. And if you keep making that kind of mistake, like installing `pyconfig` when they tell you that you need `pkg-config`, you're going to have a lot of trouble.

Comment: thanks for letting me know that I might use pyQT  instead. i just have to look up the documentation.

Comment: @user2566626: Did I even mention Qt? Anyway, yes, Qt and PyQt or PySide may be easier to install on Windows than Gtk+, but I'm not sure I'd made "easy to install on my development machine" the main criterion for choosing a GUI library. If that _is_ your main criterion, just use Tkinter, which comes built in with Python.

Comment: yeah I am going to use tinker since it is built in  Thanks for your help